# How to call controller action in hyper link in yii 2.0

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to give url for call controller action in hyperlink but when i give the url to hyper link it give 404 error .

```
<div class="panel-footer ">

        Forget Password!<?= Html::a('Forget password ', ['user%2Fforgot'])?>  
    </div>
```

when use this hyper link it not show like this :http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=user%2Fforgot.
but show the url like this.:http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=home%2Fuser%2Fforgot.
don't understand how the home show in url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `user%2Fforgot` it will be automatically done.

Try this example:

```
<div class="panel-footer ">
     Forget Password!<?= Html::a('Forget password ', ['/user/forgot'])?>  
                </div>
```

Comment: @vikash. Mark as accepted. To make it useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

You should try.

```
<div class="panel-footer ">
     Forget Password! <?= Html::a('Forget password ', ['/user/forgot'])?>  
</div>
```